# How to extract text from the plain text part of multipart/alternative?

Tags: python, email, multipart

```
# main.py
import email
from email.iterators import _structure
import sys
msg = email.message_from_string(sys.stdin.read())
_structure(msg)
```

```
./main.py <<EOF
From:  Nathaniel Borenstein <nsb@bellcore.com>
To: Ned Freed <ned@innosoft.com>
Subject: Formatted text mail
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundary42


--boundary42
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

...plain text version of message goes here....

--boundary42
Content-Type: text/richtext

.... richtext version of same message goes here ...
--boundary42
Content-Type: text/x-whatever

.... fanciest formatted version of same  message  goes  here
...
--boundary42--
EOF
```

The output

```
multipart/alternative
    text/plain
    text/richtext
    text/x-whatever
```

I can call the email module to get the structure of a multipart email message like the above. How can I extract the text/plain part of the email message? (In this particular example, it should be "...plain text version of message goes here....".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `msg.get_payload()` to get the payload of your message, and then you iterate over the parts until you find the `text/plain` part:

```
# main.py
import email
import sys

msg = email.message_from_string(sys.stdin.read())

for part in msg.get_payload():
    if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
        print(part.get_payload())
```

Given your sample input, the above code produces as output:

```
...plain text version of message goes here....
```

---

You could instead use `email.iterators.typed_subpart_iterator`, like this:

```
# main.py
import email
import email.iterators
import sys

msg = email.message_from_string(sys.stdin.read())

for part in email.iterators.typed_subpart_iterator(msg, maintype='text', subtype="plain"):
    print(part.get_payload())
```

This produces the same output as the earlier example.

---

> docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html says get_body() can work

The `get_body` method is only available on `email.message.EmailMessage`, but by default `email.message_from_string` returns a legacy `email.message.Message` object (see the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_string)).

In order to get an `email.message.EmailMessage` object, you need to pass in a `policy` parameter:

```
import email
import email.policy

msg = email.message_from_string(sys.stdin.read(), policy=email.policy.default)

print(msg.get_body().get_payload())
```

This will also produce the same output as the first example.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html says `get_body()` can work. But I don't know how to parse into the object that has the get_body() method. How to use get_body() to solve this problem?

Comment: See my update about using the `get_body` method.